# Compute prometheus time interval from grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I have a Prometheus count and sum metric to track an API

```
def query(list of objects)
```

I want to display the count of queries in a given time range as well as the number of objects queried. In grafana I can select this time interval for the dashboard from the drop down:
[image]

The selection for "Last * minutes/hours/days" works fine and is straightforward:

```
increase(metric[$__range])
```

The problem occurs when I select a specific range of `from` & `to` in grafana. How do I pick a specific time interval for prometheus? I know there is an offset modifier, but how do I compute this offset?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you get this functionality by default, Grafana will query only the specified time range (you can see that in the dashboard page URL)

Comment: Thanks, I just took a look at the HTTP requests going out. They indeed use the specific time ranges. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grafana sends the time range to the Prometheus server as part of the PromQL query, you can spot that in the Grafana dashboard page URL.
example for last 24 houres:

```
/d/Zb3f4veGk/dashboard-name?orgId=1&from=now-24h&to=now
```

example for specific time range:

```
/d/Zb3f4veGk/dashboard-name?orgId=1&from=1632122144195&to=1632294944195
```

if we check the request body payload we can see those variables in action:
[image]